# Display all categories from news item

Tags: typo3, typo3-7.6.x, typo3-extensions, tt-news

I have a news item that has more categories. If I use firstCategory then I receive as output the first chosen category, but it’s not what I want. I want to display all the categories that a news item has been marked as. I've tried following but there is no output

```
<f:if condition=“{newsItem.categories}“>
    <span class=“news-list-category label label-default test”>
       <f:for each=“{categories}” as=“category”>
               {category.title}
       </f:for>
    </span>
</f:if>
```

Comment: Could you try it again with `<f:for each=“{newsItem.categories}” as=“category”>`?

Comment: Thanks, that had worked!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In for loop use `newsItem.categories` instead of `categories`. Like below.

```
<f:if condition=“{newsItem.categories}“>
    <span class=“news-list-category label label-default test”>
       <f:for each=“{newsItem.categories}” as=“category”>
               {category.title}
       </f:for>
    </span>
</f:if>
```